# WITH unexpected error for multi-line queries in SQLDelight-PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, postgresql-15, sqldelight

I am trying to run an insert query where it will check if the record exist and make an entry only if there is no record. And since it is an multi-line query i have to enclose the entire query in curly braces. Here is my query:

```
insert
{
WITH
  extant AS (
    SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE (phone) = ('108123403115')
  )
  inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO my_table (phone)
    SELECT '108123403115'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM extant)
    RETURNING id;
  )
SELECT id FROM inserted
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM extant
}
```

And the error that am getting is:

```
'{' expected, got 'WITH'
2    WITH
     ^^^^
```

I have setup the multi-line query under the tag *insert* and tried taking off the curly braces as well. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: 1) `{}` are not correct syntax, see [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html). 2) Use `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` per [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).